# Cross product order of operations question

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

The question I have is:

> Is $\overrightarrow{u} \times (\overrightarrow{v} \times
>  \overrightarrow{w})=(\overrightarrow{u} \times \overrightarrow{v})
>  \times \overrightarrow{w}$? What is the meaning of $\overrightarrow{u}
>  \times \overrightarrow{v} \times \overrightarrow{w}$? Explain.
>   **Hint**: Try ($\overrightarrow{i} \times \overrightarrow{j}) \times \overrightarrow{k}$.

I don't understand what $\overrightarrow{u}$, $\overrightarrow{v}$, and $\overrightarrow{w}$ are supposed to be? Are they equivalent to the $i,j,k$ unit vectors?

Things I tried:

1. I tried the *Hint* given above, computing ($\overrightarrow{i} \times \overrightarrow{j}) \times \overrightarrow{k}$. Which I believe gives $0$? Since $\overrightarrow{i} \times \overrightarrow{j} =\overrightarrow{k}$, and $ \overrightarrow{k} \times \overrightarrow{k}=0$?

I'm not sure where else to go on this question, since I cant figure out what what $\overrightarrow{u}$, $\overrightarrow{v}$, and $\overrightarrow{w}$ are supposed to be...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are supposed to be arbitrary vectors.

To show that cross product is not associative, you need only to find one counter-example, which is what the hint supposed to guide you. But the hint is a wrong one.

Try consider
$$\hat{i}\times\hat{i}\times\hat{j}$$
instead.

Comment: $\hat{i}\times\hat{i}\times\hat{j}= 0\times\hat{j}$?

Comment: That's the answer for $(\hat{i}\times \hat{i})\times \hat{j}$. What about  $\hat{i}\times (\hat{i}\times \hat{j})$?

Comment: $\hat{i}\times (\hat{i}\times \hat{j})=\hat{i}\times \hat{k}$?

Comment: So are they equal?

Comment: No, the results aren't equal. I still don't understand though how that allows us to say whether or not $\overrightarrow{u} \times (\overrightarrow{v} \times
 \overrightarrow{w})=(\overrightarrow{u} \times \overrightarrow{v})
 \times \overrightarrow{w}$?

Comment: @LovesLinearAlgebra Is $a+b=a-b$? Try $a=1$, $b=2$, what can you conclude?

Comment: Ok, I see. I'm still not sure on the second question of this exercise: What is the meaning of $\overrightarrow{u}
 \times \overrightarrow{v} \times \overrightarrow{w}$?

Comment: It is not well-defined because cross product is not associative. It leads to ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The objects ${\bf u}, {\bf v}, {\bf w}$ appear to be arbitrary vectors in $\Bbb R^3$.

The hint looks badly misleading to me, since both (as you've computed) the indicated iterated product and the same product carried out in other order (that is, with the parentheses in the other possible location) are $0$. Instead, try comparing
$$({\bf i} \times {\bf i}) \times {\bf j} \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad {\bf i} \times ({\bf i} \times {\bf j}) .$$

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter would explain their objection?

Comment: (I wasn't the downvoter...) $({\bf i} \times {\bf i}) \times {\bf j}= {\bf 0} \times {\bf j} \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad {\bf i} \times ({\bf i} \times {\bf j}) = {\bf i} \times {\bf k}$?

Comment: Correct---and if you simplify both expressions, are the results equal?

Comment: No, the results aren't equal. I still don't understand though how that allows us to say whether or not $\overrightarrow{u} \times (\overrightarrow{v} \times
 \overrightarrow{w})=(\overrightarrow{u} \times \overrightarrow{v})
 \times \overrightarrow{w}$?

Comment: You've just shown that the two disagree for some particular choice of ${\mb u}, {\mb v}, {\mb w}$, which means the identity does hold in general (i.e., for all choices of those vectors).

Comment: Oops, sorry, that should of course be $\bf u$, etc.